# Different value in ui-knob bar and center value

Tags: angularjs, jquery-knob

I am using [ng-knob](https://radmie.github.io/ng-knob/) library to draw some charts in my angular project, the charts load perfectly, but I have a new requirement that is put different values for the text showed in the donut center and value in the progress bar of the chart.

In the image below, the left chart have the actual behaviour, and the right chart is the desired behavior.

[image: Donut Charts with diferents values in bar progress and center text value]

I have researched in google without success, Can you have any ideas how to do this without change the core of the library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the "max" property in the config to 15.38461538461538 which 10 is 65% of.

Comment: thanks Robert, but 10 is a value that can be variable, for example in one chart I have 8,74 and in the bar I need 77%, two values are independient and not related it, ant this values will be dynamically

Comment: I think you will need to modify the libraries source code to accomplish this, it doesn't look like it can be accomplished via their config.